# Generate Stats using Aggregation MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm newbie in MongoDB aggregation.

I'm playing with a small web application to store attendance on a daily basis, and report on it based on month and year.

this is the attendance collection on DB :

```
{
        _id : 5f3b7f85a189d04eec4ec2e8
        dated :2020-03-18T12:01:25.348+00:00
        empId:"10013"
        employee:5f2b66620ec17b4b1034549a
        weekOff:false
        inTime:2020-08-18T12:01:34.308+00:00
        outTime:2020-08-18T12:10:34.308+00:00
        present:true
        startLate:true
        leaveEarly:true
} ........
```

how do I get statistics like this :

```
{
    month : 01,
    year : 2020,
    present : 75 %
    absent : 25%
    startLate : 10%
    leaveEarly: 25%
},
{
    month : 02,
    year : 2020,
    present : 80 %
    absent : 22%
    startLate : 20%
    leaveEarly: 05%
}, ...
```

I was trying but unable to get it right

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: actually I'm very new at this, just trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by destructuring the date into its constituent parts using the [`$dateToParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/) operator.

After that group based on month and year, accumulate all `present`, `startLate` and `leaveEarly` and the count too.

After grouping, project the required fields and calculate the percentage.

Here's a [`fiddle`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ya0sKUi94dr) of the below.

```
var pipeline = [
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateToParts: {
          date: "$dated"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: "$date.month",
        year: "$date.year"
      },
      sum: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      present: {
          $sum: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ['$present', true] },
              then: 1,
              else: 0
            }
          }
      },
      absent: {
          $sum: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ['$present', false] },
              then: 1,
              else: 0
            }
          }
      },
      startLate: {
          $sum: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ['$startLate', true] },
              then: 1,
              else: 0
            }
          }
       },
       leaveEarly: {
          $sum: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ['$leaveEarly', true] },
              then: 1,
              else: 0
            }
          }
       }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
        month: '$id.month',
        year: '$id.year',
        "present": {
            $multiply: [
                { $divide: ["$present", "$sum"] },
                100
            ]
        },
        "absent": {
            $multiply: [
                { $divide: ["$absent", "$sum"] },
                100
            ]
        },
        "startLate": {
            $multiply: [
                { $divide: ["$startLate", "$sum"] },
                100
            ]
        },
        "leaveEarly": {
            $multiply: [
                { $divide: ["$leaveEarly", "$sum"] },
                100
            ]
        }
    }
  }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: Thank You @Kunal Mukherjee for the help highly appreciated